# Faces tilting and warping

Tags: faces

I haven't been using Blender for very long but one issue that I always seem to have is that some of my faces seem to bend and warp in weird ways. I've looked up this issue online but wasn't able to find a solution or even anyone else experiencing the issue. I've attached some screenshots with examples of my problem.[Faces warping in a different way even when a mirror is (and has always been) active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gKbc.png)[image: Faces seem to warp in one direction after remeshing][image: Strange looking UV's in the modeling tab]

Comment: From your question I don't really understand what is your problem, please clarify what should happen and what is happening right now

Comment: The pattern in your second image appears to be an example of _Z-fighting_. This happens when two surfaces exactly overlap.  That suggests that you sometimes use the face command when a different set of vertices than you meant were selected.  If you added a blend file showing the problem to your question, it should be easy to check if that's the issue ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to which faces bend and warp? 